# Cannot add value to object property after findOne() inside a for-loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
app.get('/calculatePrice', function(req, res) {
  let toyIds = req.query.id,
    qty = req.query.qty,
    totalPrice = 0,
    subtotal = 0,
    result = {"items": [], "totalPrice": totalPrice},
    item = {};

    for (let i = 0; i < toyIds.length; i++) {
        Toy.findOne({id: toyIds[0]}, { id: 1, price: 1, _id: 0 }, function(err, toy) {
        if (toy) {
            item[item] = toy.id; //doesnt work
            item[qty] = qty[0]; //doesnt work
            item[subtotal] = (toy.price * Number(qty[0])); //doesnt work
            totalPrice += item[subtotal]; //doesnt work

        }
    });
    result.items.push(item);
  }
  res.json(result);
});
```

I am trying to find specific toys inside mongodb by their respective ToyIds provided by the url "/calculateprice?id[0]=1234&qty[0]=2&id[1]=1235&qty[1]=1&id[2]=1236&qty[2]=5".

However, after it finds one, I cant seem to use the data to add values to my "item" object properties.

I have done some research and I am guessing it has to do with Toy.findOne being async but I really don't understand and can't seem to figure out a solution myself. Help and explaination to a noob learning node/mongodb would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace loop + `findOne` with `find` and then you need to move `res.json(result)` inside a callback to make it run when your async process is done:

```
app.get('/calculatePrice', function(req, res) {
    let toyIds = req.query.id;
    let result = { items: [] };
    Toy.find({id: {$in: toyIds}}, function(err, toys) {
        if(err) {
            res.status(500).json({error: true});
        }
        if (toys) {
            // process the result
            // push toys data to result.items
        }
        res.json(result);
    });
});
```